# Keep getting "TypeError: Cannot perform 'getPrototypeOf' when i console.log the state on redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to using redux-tool kit. I am trying to map through the orders and set the order as confirmed when the button is clicked on. So far i am just trying to view the state before looping through it. But every time i click the confirm order button  i keep getting this error message
TypeError: Cannot perform 'getPrototypeOf'

I am really not sure what I am doing wrong. I have added the link to my sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-hugle-ioo2nb?file=/redux/store.js

```
Below is the code i am having issues with. Any help would be really appreciated
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const orders = createSlice({
  name: "orders",
  initialState: [
    { id: 1, name: "Pizza", is_confirmed: "0" },
    { id: 2, name: "Hamburher", is_confirmed: "0" }
  ],
  reducers: {
    addToOrders: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
      state.concat(action.payload);
    },

    confirmOrder: (state, action) => {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      console.log(id);

       console.log(state,"state"); // Error happens here

      return state;



    }
  }
});
```

Comment: On the code sandbox there is another error
`could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>`

Comment: [I fixed your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-flower-kcmwtj?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: You need to import the `current` function from `@reduxjs/toolkit` and use `console.log(current(state),"state")`.  I can't replicate your particular error message.  I'm assuming that this is the issue unless you can create a reproducible example that gives the "TypeError: Cannot perform 'getPrototypeOf'" message.